# In Blogger, how can I change the definition of courier which is by default <span style="font-family: Courier New, Courier, monospace;">

Tags: fonts, customization, blogger

I am using Blogger and want to publish my code in courier format. However, the current setting is

> `<span style="font-family: Courier New, Courier, monospace;"> Courier</span>`

(When I select a block of text and go to the html view, I can find about this)

However, the courier font in Windows and IOS are quite thin and easy to identify from the default font (seems arial). But in Ubuntu, it is a bit difficult to tell the difference. If I change the font to

> `<span style="font-family: Courier;"> Courier</span>`

or maybe

> `<span style="font-family: Courier, Courier New, monospace;"> Courier</span>`

so that I can have only courier or highest courier priority?

I can add a new "code" style using Template-> Customize->Advanced->add CSS. But still the problem is that I need to change the code manually. Is it possible for me using CSS to overload smartly that I can change all Courier New to Courier?

I have tried the code format guide in this link through some other stackoverflow questions, it is good for color and indent but I still cannot change the courier new to courier..
http://www.craftyfella.com/2010/01/syntax-highlighting-with-blogger-engine.html

Thanks very much for your help. I do not want to change all the html tag one by one..